# vuejs2-ace-editor: accessing editor instance

Tags: vuejs2

I am using this Vue2 component for ACE editor:
https://github.com/chairuosen/vue2-ace-editor

This is how I add the component to my app

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue_app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!',
        editor_content: 'somecontent'
    },
    methods:{
        editorInit:function (el) {
            require('brace/mode/json');
            require('brace/theme/tomorrow');
        }
    },
    components: {
        editor:require('vue2-ace-editor')
    }
});
```

And when I put this into my HTML everything works correctly:

```
<editor v-model="editor_content" @init="editorInit();" lang="json" theme="tomorrow" width="500" height="100"></editor>
```

However the editor renders with a gutter which I don't need, so I want to access the editor instance to tweak some properties.

The source code for this component says it emits an event on mount:

```
mounted: function () {
    var vm = this;
    var lang = this.lang||'text';
    var theme = this.theme||'chrome';

    require('brace/ext/emmet');

    var editor = vm.editor = ace.edit(this.$el);

    this.$emit('init',editor);

    editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;
    editor.setOption("enableEmmet", true);
    editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/'+lang);
    editor.setTheme('ace/theme/'+theme);
    editor.setValue(this.value,1);

    editor.on('change',function () {
        var content = editor.getValue();
        vm.$emit('input',content);
        vm.contentBackup = content;
    });


}
```

How and where do I catch this event and access the `editor` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already listening to the `init` event and calling the `editorInit` method. However, you need to pass the data being emitted by the `<editor>` component.

You can either do that explicitly by using `$event`:

```
<editor v-model="editor_content" @init="editorInit($event)" ...></editor>
```

Or implicitly by simply providing the method name as the event handler:

```
<editor v-model="editor_content" @init="editorInit" ...></editor>
```

Then, in your `editorInit` method, the param being passed in will be the instance of the editor. And I believe you can specify to not render the gutter like so:

```
editorInit:function (editor) {
  editor.renderer.setShowGutter(false)
  require('brace/mode/json');
  require('brace/theme/tomorrow');
}
```